# ssh portforwarding unix

Tags: unix, ssh

I am trying to use local port forwarding to access remote host over a firewall and am able to do so using the command below.

```
ssh -L 23456:remotehost:10000 localhost

>telnet localhost 23456
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.


>telnet 170.19.120.207 23456
Trying 170.19.120.207...
telnet: connect to address 170.19.120.207: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Looks like portforwarding is happening on loopback and anything with the hostname is getting rejected. Can someone help me to get around this, as I am sure there is/should be a way

Comment: Not a programming question. Flagged for move to ServerFault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems it is working correctly 'telnet localhost 23456' works!

`telnet 170.19.120.207 23456` shouldn't work, unless 170.19.120.207 points to your host. If you want that you need to enable gateway functionality:

```
ssh -g -L 23456:remotehost:10000 localhost
```